# Drupal programatically create a form with a for condition

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to create a form to create a person, and this person can have some relation with another one (like a wife, husband, child, ..), so I try to create something with a button to add a relation, here is my code :

```
if (empty($form_state['number_liaisons'])) {
  $form_state['number_liaisons'] = 1;
}

$form['info_contact']['liaison'] = array(
  "#type" => "fieldset",
  "#title" => "Liaisons",
  "#attributes" => array("class" => array("center"))
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['number_liaisons']; $i++) {
  $form['info_contact']['liaison'][$i] = array(
    "#type" => "fieldset",
    "#title" => "Liaison",
    "#attributes" => array("class" => array("center"))
  );

  $form['info_contact']['liaison'][$i]['contact'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Personne a lier"),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'crm/autocomplete_liaison',
  );

  $form['info_contact']['liaison'][$i]['type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t("Type de liaison"),
    '#options' => Array('enfant' => 'Enfant', 'conjoint' => 'conjoint'),
    '#empty_option' => t('- Choisir un type de liaison -'),
  );
}

$form['info_contact']['liaison']['add_item'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Add liaison'),
  '#submit' => array('liaison_add_item'),
  '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
);

if ($form_state['number_liaisons'] > 1) {

  $form['info_contact']['liaison'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Remove liaison'),
    '#submit' => array('liaison_remove_item'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
  );
}
```

And the two methods to add / remove a relation :

```
function liaison_add_item($form, &$form_state)
{
  $form_state['number_liaisons']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
}

function liaison_remove_item($form, &$form_state)
{
  if ($form_state['number_liaisons'] > 1) {
    $form_state['number_liaisons']--;
  }

  $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the "Add liaison" button all the fields disappear, and when I click on the remove liaison the fields came back.
So when I have more than 1 in my `$form_state['number_liaisons']` the for doesn't show my fields.

Anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the liaisons all share the same field name, the $form_state doesn't really care if they are nested. So try renaming to something like;

["contact_{$i}"] rather than just ['contact']